# ASP.NET MVC5 Generic Translation method for database entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two methods for a database entity which gets the translation for selected language if it has one, or the default language translation.

```
public string GetName(int? LanguageId, int? DefaultLanguageId)
{
    string retval = "";
    var textInSelectedLanguage = this.CategoryTexts.Where(w => w.LanguageId == LanguageId).SingleOrDefault();
    if (textInSelectedLanguage == null)
    {
        retval = this.CategoryTexts.Where(w => w.LanguageId == DefaultLanguageId).SingleOrDefault().Name;
    }
    else
    {
        retval = textInSelectedLanguage.Name;
    }
    return retval;
}

public string GetDescription(int? LanguageId, int? DefaultLanguageId)
{
    string retval = "";
    var textInSelectedLanguage = this.CategoryTexts.Where(w => w.LanguageId == LanguageId).SingleOrDefault();
    if (textInSelectedLanguage == null)
    {
        retval = this.CategoryTexts.Where(w => w.LanguageId == DefaultLanguageId).SingleOrDefault().Description;
    }
    else
    {
        retval = textInSelectedLanguage.Description;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

As you can see they are very similar. If I have more properties to translate, this won't be a good implementation. The behavior is similar for the other translations.

How can reduce this code to one method?

I tried to use reflection but I didn't had any results.

Later...

I reduced my code to one method which return me the an entity instance with all the properties in the selected language or default language:

```
public CategoryText GetTranslation(int? DesiredLanguageId, int? DefaultLanguageId)
{
    CategoryText retval = null;
    var textInSelectedLanguage = this.CategoryTexts.Where(w => w.LanguageId == DesiredLanguageId).SingleOrDefault();
    if (textInSelectedLanguage == null)
    {
        retval = this.CategoryTexts.Where(w => w.LanguageId == DefaultLanguageId).SingleOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        retval = textInSelectedLanguage;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

I think this method can be easily made generic by trying to find a way to replace my `CategoryTexts` Dbset with any other DbSet database entity. How can I do this?

Comment: What are the other database entities that you want to operate on? Do they have a common base class or interface with the `LanguageId` property on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an appropriate base class you could write it:-

```
public T GetTranslation<T>(DbSet<T> set, int? DesiredLanguageId, int? DefaultLanguageId)
    where T:SomeBaseClassThatHasPropertyLanguageId
{
    return 
       set.SingleOrDefault(w => w.LanguageId == DesiredLanguageId) ??
       set.SingleOrDefault(w => w.LanguageId == DefaultLanguageId);
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem in another way too. Please take a look and tell me your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow solved this.

I have an Internationalization class which with the following method:

```
public static T GetDbEntityTranslation<T>(ITranslatable Entity)
{
    return (T)Entity.GetTranslation<T>(GetDefaultLanguage().Id, GetChosenLanguage().Id);
}
```

The ITranslatable interface:

```
public interface ITranslatable
{
    T GetTranslation<T>(int? DesiredLanguageId, int? DefaultLanguageId);
}
```

My category class:

```
public partial class Category : ITranslatable
{
    private LSEntities db = new LSEntities();

    public T GetTranslation<T>(int? DesiredLanguageId, int? DefaultLanguageId)
    {
        CategoryText retval = null;
        retval = db.CategoryTexts.Where(w => w.LanguageId == DesiredLanguageId && w.CategoryId == this.Id).SingleOrDefault()
            ?? this.CategoryTexts.Where(w => w.LanguageId == DefaultLanguageId && w.CategoryId == this.Id).SingleOrDefault()
            ?? this.CategoryTexts.Where(w => w.CategoryId == this.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (retval == null)
            throw new Exception("No translation found for this object");
        return (T)(object)retval;
    }
}
```

The problem was that I need to get my translation based on my category `ID` which is stored in `Category` class. My translations are searched in `CategoryTexts` property.

Comment: You should be able to do this without any casting if you get your inheritance relationships correct.  `(T)(object)` is nasty.  But I suggest you discuss coding style on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ as that's the more appropriate venue for code-review questions.